# Part of a word bold in reStructuredText

Tags: documentation, formatting, restructuredtext

How can I make a part of a word bold in reStructuredText?

Here is an example of what I need: ".rst stands for **r**e**s**tructured **t**ext."

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I was surprised that you could not simply write

```
.rst stands for **r**e**s**tructured **t**ext.
```

but the [reStructuredText specification](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup) indeed states that inline markup must be followed by white-space or one of `-` `.` `,` `:` `;` `!` `?` `\` `/` `'` `"` `)` `]` `}` or `>`, so the above string of reStructuredText is *not* valid. However, only a minor change is required to get valid [*character* markup](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup) with backslash escapes. Changing the above to

```
.rst stands for **r**\ e\ **s**\ tructured **t**\ ext.
```

works fine. To see this in action try the [online reST to HTML converter](http://www.tele3.cz/jbar/rest/rest.html).

Comment: Just to add that in *some* cases you can get away without space after the backslash. In this case, `**r**\e\ **s**\ tructured **t**\ext`. (I'm not impressed by this aspect of reST, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the setting [character-level-inline-markup](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup). Then, the example markup `.rst stands for **r**e**s**tructured **t**ext.` works as expected.