# How to strikethrough substrings without spaces in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, strikethrough

I need to <strike>strike</strike> substrings without spaces in Sphinx .rst file to transform it to HTML in a similar manner as `<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">strike</span>substring`. The following example is not working for me. Is it possible?

conf.py

```py
extensions = ["sphinxnotes.strike"]
```

index.rst

```
:strike:`strike`substring
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known peculiarity of ReStructuredText, see, e.g., [Part of a word bold in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771480/part-of-a-word-bold-in-restructuredtext).

All you need is an escaped space after the substring:

```
:strike:`strike`\ substring
```

Comment: There is also the Docutils configuration setting [character-level-inline-markup](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup)

Comment: @G.Milde, nice, I didn't know that.  Would you like to add it as another answer, on how to configure Sphinx for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the Docutils configuration setting [character-level-inline-markup](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup) that lifts the no-whitespace-restriction around inline markup strings.
It could be set in a `docutils.conf` [configuration file](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#configuration-files) in the same directory as `setpu.py`.

However, I would not recommend this for a complete Sphinx project --- you may need to escape a lot of "false positives".
Exception: it may make sense in projects using a language without inter-word spaces.